# Sun light illumination on a lower floor vs high building closely

Tags: building-design, building-physics

there is an investor that wants to build very close to our building. In case we agree, the buildings will stand like on the pictures below, 3 meters apart from each other. I tried to draw them in proper scale so I hope that is more or less correct. This is in 43.20 latitude.

My question is, in case we agree for one reason or another, is it possible to ensure enough sun light during the day on our floor?

The immediate idea I've got was to request them paint the wall facing towards us in white pearly  paint. I am wondering though if this is going to be good enough as well whether there are some other clever ways to direct sun light to our windows.

Any good products or services available in Europe would be welcome (hope this will be alright according to StackExchange rules).

The matters are subject to negotiation and I expect investor to be helpful in case any measures involve their cooperation, even slight building design changes might be possible.

Thanks a lot for any insights!

[image]
[image]